# Referencing components of objects from an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean, components

I'm trying to make a "thing" that checks/unchecks a specific object's interactable checkbox from an array by using player pref integers. The problem I'm having is I can't seem to reference specific objects from an array, please help.

Here's some script:

```
//This part is from the Start function.

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++) {

            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("button" + i) == null) {

                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("button" + i, 1);

            }

            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("button" + i) == 1) {

                button.interactable = true;

            } else {

                button.interactable = false;

            }

        }



void Update () {

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++) {

            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("button" + i) == 0) {

                button.interactable = false;

            }

        }

    }
```

The areas where you can see button.interactable = true/false are where I'm having problems.

Comment: Instead of having an integer variable in the class, have you considered just having an instance of a button in the class and showing it on the form?  This way you can interact with the button through the instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `button` defined somewhere else; I assume you are missing the concept of array index accessors; you might want to use `buttons[i]` instead of `button`.

Comment: Omg it worked thank you very much :D Sorry I'm so new to C# that I'm still getting used to the syntax needed for different stuff.